# nginx proxy_pass configuration to virtualhost

Tags: apache, nginx, proxypass

I would like to redirect to an  external URL which is hosted as a apache virtual host.
nginx resolves the url which obviously does little to resolve to the correct web root on the server.

```
 server {
            server_name localhost;
            location / {
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_pass http://www.urlforvirtualhost.com;
            }
    }
```

The question is how do I allow proxy_pass without nginx resolving the ip-address of the URL?